# Face Recognition with LBPHFaceRecognizer always predict as same person.Even when anonymous person to face the camera?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have a data set for myself.

My code works perfectly when i go to the camera. But I test again with unknown person the program predicts again as me. It should return -1 or null !!!

I run in python3 and latest version of cv2 from opencv.

->detector.py

```
import cv2,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
import pickle,time

# Root directory
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()#cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "Classifiers/face.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
path = 'dataSet'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cam.isOpened())
#font = cv2.InitFont(cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

#Creates a font
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

while True:
    ret, im =cam.read()
    print('im: ',im,' ;ROOT_DIR:',ROOT_DIR)
    print('ret: ',ret)
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(100, 100), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x-50,y-50),(x+w+50,y+h+50),(225,0,0),2)
        print("nbr_predicted: ",nbr_predicted)
        if(nbr_predicted==7 or nbr_predicted==8):
             nbr_predicted='Vishesh 1'
        else:
            nbr_predicted="Unknown Person"
        cv2.putText(im,str(nbr_predicted)+"--"+str(conf), (x,y+h),font, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) #Draw the text
        cv2.imshow('im',im)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Only the person in middle must be Vishesh. But even my bros are predicted as Vishesh. Where could this be possibly going wrong ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ecognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]) returns the prediction index that shows the number of the person in training set and confidence for it for all persons in the training set with a confidence value.
Since your photo is the only one in the training set, it returns nbr_predicted is always your ID and confidence shows the "probability" that the image send to predict function is you.
hence update your code as:

```
    if(nbr_predicted==7 and conf<120):
         nbr_predicted='Vishesh 1'
    else:
        nbr_predicted="Unknown Person"
```

the value of confidence usually depends on your data, but the lower the better.
you should adjust the threshold

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to adjust the threshold, and why did you choose the 120 value?

Comment: The threshold are really depend on your application, precision that you expect and also your data. So an easy way might be tuning them by try and error to get better results.

Comment: CascadeClassifier uses euclidean distance as the measure of similarity and in this case mostly under 120 is considered to be a match between two vectors.